# How to speed up the construction of a dict whose values are filled conditionally?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to build a new dictionary whose values are filled conditionally. The problem I have is; I need to search over millions of items to do so. Below is my attempt to do it with a modest amount of information, but in practice, I need to do this same thing with something many hundreds times its size and it will take hours.

```
import torch, copy
import numpy as np

# initialize model
class mlp1(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, num_hidden, num_classes):
        super(mlp1, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.input_layer = torch.nn.Linear(num_features, num_hidden)
        self.out_layer = torch.nn.Linear(num_hidden, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.input_layer(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        logits = self.out_layer(x)
        probas = torch.softmax(logits, dim=1)
        return logits, probas

# instantiate model
model = mlp1(num_features=28*28, num_hidden=100, num_classes=10)

# initial params
initial_dict = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

# trained params
trained_dict = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())  # pretend its different

# masks
mask = {
         name: torch.tensor(np.random.choice([False, True],
                                              size=torch.numel(weight),
                                              p=[0.5, 0.5]).reshape(weight.shape))
                for name, weight in initial_dict.items()
                }

# create a new model state
#### how to improve this ####
result = {}
# for each key
for key in initial_dict.keys():
    # if key is not in the new dict
    if key not in result:
        # add it
        result[key] = []
    # get current shape to reshape later
    current_shape = initial_dict[key].shape
    # for each value in each dict
    for v1, v2, v3 in zip(initial_dict[key], trained_dict[key], mask[key]):
        # if multidimensional
        if len(v1.shape) >= 1:
            # loop again
            for vv1, vv2, vv3 in zip(v1, v2, v3):
                # if mask condition is met
                if vv3.item() == True:
                    # append trained dict values
                    result[key].append(vv2.item())
                    # other wise
                else:
                    # append initial dict values
                    result[key].append(vv1.item())
        # else if not multidimensional
        elif len(v1.shape) <= 1:
            # if mask condition is met
            if v3.item() == True:
                # if do the same as bove
                result[key].append(vv2.item())
            else:
                result[key].append(vv1.item())
    # turn key to tensor
    result[key] = torch.as_tensor(result[key])
    # reshape
    result[key] = result[key].reshape(current_shape)
#### how to improve this ####
```

### Changes based on helpful answer

I am probably not hitting the mark judging from no real improvement with what I have done.

```
def process(initial_value, trained_value, mask_value):
    # get initial shape
    shape = initial_value.shape
    # create storage
    output = []
    # for each array of data in the dict
    for m_array1, m_array2, m_array3 in zip(initial_value, trained_value, mask_value):
        # if a certain shape
        if len(shape) >= 2:
            # go through each tensor at the same time
            for tensor1, tensor2, tensor3 in zip(m_array1, m_array2, m_array3):
                # if mask is True
                if tensor3.item() is True:
                    # append tensor from trained_value
                    output.append(tensor2.item())
                else:
                    output.append(tensor1.item())
        else:
            # if single-dimensional array
            if m_array3.item() is True:
                # if true, append tensor from trained_value
                output.append(m_array2.item())
            else:
                # otherwise add the initial_value
                output.append(m_array1.item())
    # turn key to tensor
    output = torch.as_tensor(output)
    # reshape
    output = output.reshape(shape)
    return output

%timeit result_dict = {k: process(v, trained_dict[k], mask[k]) for k, v in initial_dict.items()}
```

### Edit 2:

The solution to this is to use vectorized operations, which I suppose should have known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips for you to improve performance:

Your result dictionary has keys which are based on the initial dictionary keys. And when you unpack initial dictionary keys (which are unique), you are guaranteed to not see the same key twice. Therefore you can save yourself the `if key not in` check.

---

Unpack key and value together instead of using key and then looking up value.

```
for key, value in initial_dict.items():
  print(key, value)
```

---

Use a dictionary comprehension (for optimized C code underneath) instead of making an empty dictionary and adding to it.

e.g.

```py
initial = {"a": 10, "b": 11}
doubled = {k: v*2 for k, v in initial.items()}
# { "a": 20, "b": 22 }
```

---

In order to use dictionary comprehension, you are going to wrap you logic of many lines into a function and call that. Which is good anyway to make your code more readable and reusable.

```py
def process(initial_value, trained_value, mask_value):
    shape = initial_value.shape
    output = []
    # Your logic...
    output.append(1)
    output.append(2)

    return output 


result_dict = {k: process(v, trained_dict[v], mask[v]) for k, v in initial_dict.items()
```

Your use of nested looping for multidimensional array also sounds like an area that could be optimized. Can do you it with a single iteration instead of nesting? Can you use dictionary or list comprehension to at least get speed boost on current logic?

---

Style comments:

For Python style, use `is True` rather than `== True` when it comes to boolean.

Your v2 and vv2 etc. variables are obscure. They need appropriate names. Then you won't have to comment that this is trained or initial.

Also your if and elif statement only has two branches and one is guaranteed to be hit, so could make it just if and else.

Comment: The super detailed post is greatly appreciated. I am thinking that I am not hitting the mark as what I have done yields basically the same run time, judging from a quick %timeit. I have added what I have done with the fn above in an edit if you may continue to be so kind to help me better improve this process.

Comment: Code looks much better. The comments on every second like add little meaning and actually make the code harder to read. I'm disappointed you didn't see a speed improvement. Maybe you can use a np array instead of output list? Numpy and Pandas have been heavily optimized at the C level and there are also many ways to so the same task in those and get different speed.

Comment: I can also recommend using Python profiling using a library or IDE tool. That will tell you _which_ part of your logic is taking the most time to compute and then you optimize that.

Comment: How large is your input data? Maybe a few hours is reasonable and you just leave it as a long running task. You can speed it up by running it is on beefed up hardware in the cloud and even splitting the data into multiple sections and processing in parallel on multiple machines.

Comment: You can even try that locally. Using multi core processing with a Python library can be tricky to get into within a single script. But maybe you can start you script in 4 terminal windows and use 4 cores (you'll need to research how to make sure a different core is used each time) and then you'll get 4x faster by processing in parallel. Of course you'll have to split the input data between them and re combine the 4 output pieces of data.